# LightingConfirm Modal not inheriting Experience Cloud Theme

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, experience-cloud, theme-branding

I have a LWC in Experience Cloud, where we have made some simple updates to the Theme e.g. changed the Action Color

When I use something like this, the theme works as expected:

```
 <lightning-button slot="actions" variant="brand" onclick={handleNewRecord} label="Add Household Member"></lightning-button>
```

But when I implement LightningConfirm, it is showing the standard variant colors, not the Theme I am using?

```
const result = await LightningConfirm.open({
            message: 'Are you sure you want to remove this Household Member?',
            variant: 'headerless',
            label: 'this is the aria-label value',
            // setting theme would have no effect
        });
```

When I look in the Dev Console, I see this as the class the style is being applied to:

```
slds-button_brand[lwc-6jtsd8ngusp],
```

Is there something I need to do with the way I call the Confirm, or does it just not support Themes, and I need to implement the LightningModal (assuming I can style that since it is i's own component?)

**EDIT**

Using Lightning Modal **does** work without any additional CSS, so seems to be the way LightningConfirm is called in the page?